# A module with a store

Tags: reference, ocaml, record

It happens quite often that it is costly to calculate a property from a value. So it would be better to be able to store the property once it is calculated. I am wondering how to code this properly.

Let's take an example. Assume we have a type integer, and very often we need to calculate prime factors of a value of such type (let's assume the prime factors of a negative integer is `None`):

```
module I =
struct
  type t = C of int
  type pf = (int list) option 

  let calculate_prime_factors (x: t) : pf =
    (* a costly function to calculate prime factors *)
    ... ...

  let get_prime_factors (x: t) : pf =
    calculate_prime_factors x
end

let () = 
  let v = I.C 100 in
  let pf_1 = I.get_prime_factors v in
  let pf_2 = I.get_prime_factors v in
  let pf_3 = I.get_prime_factors v in
  ...
```

At the moment, `get_prime_factors` just calls `calculate_prime_factors`, as a consequence, all the calculations of `pf_1`, `pf_2`, `pf_3` are time consuming. I would like to have a mechanism to enable storing prime factors inside the module, so that as long as the integer does not change, the second and third times of `get_prime_factors` just read what have been stored.

Does anyone know how to modify the module `I` to achieve this?

It is possible that we need references to make this mechanism possible (eg, `let vr = ref (I.C 100) in ...`). It is OK for me to use references. But I don't know how to trigger automatically `calculate_prime_factors` if the hold value (ie, `!vr`) is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, that you're looking for this solution:

```
module I = struct 
  type t = {
     c : int;
     mutable result : int option;
  }

  let create c = {c; result = None}

  let calculate_prime_factors t = match t.result with
    | Some r -> r
    | None -> 
       let r = do_calculate t.c in
       t.result <- Some r;
       r
end
```

This is called memoizing. And this particular example can be solved even easier, with `Lazy` computations.

```
  module I = struct
    type t = int Lazy.t  
    let create c = lazy (do_calculate c)
    let calculate_prime_factors = Lazy.force
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), no ?

You could try this :

```
module I =
  struct

  type t = C of int
  type pf = (int list) option 

  let calculate_prime_factors (x: t) : pf =
    (* a costly function to calculate prime factors *)
    ... ...

  module HI = Hashtbl.Make (struct 
    type t = C of int 
    let equal = (=) 
    let hash (C x) = x
  end)

  let get_prime_factors =
    let h = Hashtbl.create 17 in
    fun x ->
      try Hashtbl.find h x 
    with
      Not_found -> let pf = calculate_prime_factors x in
                   Hashtbl.add h x pf;
                   pf
end

let () = 
  let v = I.C 100 in
  let pf_1 = I.get_prime_factors v in
  let pf_2 = I.get_prime_factors v in
  let pf_3 = I.get_prime_factors v in
  ...
```

You could adapt it for negative integers (with exceptions, for example, which is better than options) but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following :

```
let get_prime_factors x =
  match get x  with
  | None ->
    let res = calculate_prime_factors x 
    in
    begin
      set x res ;
      res
    end
  | Some res -> res 
;;
```

You need a mutable data structure accessed by `get` and `set`. For instance, with a reference on a list (but you may prefer a hashtable) :

```
let my_storage = ref [] (* or something mutable *)

let get x = 
  if List.mem_assoc x !my_storage
  then Some (List.assoc x !my_storage)
  else None

let set x r =
  my_storage := (x,r) :: !my_storage ;;
```

You can also use exceptions instead of the `option` type (`None` and `Some _`).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, which stores the pair of integer and its prime factors outside. It should work, but I am rather looking for a mechanism that stores the result inside the module...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can put `my_storage` in the module.

Comment: I try to figure out a solution with a record type `{ v: t; pf: pf }` inside the module `I`. Thus, the integer `v` and its prime factors `pf` are always stored together. That's what I mean by "inside the module"...

Comment: Ok, I suggest `{ v : t ; mutable p : pf }` .

Comment: @SoftTimur, looks like that you're confusing definitions. The module is whatever is defined between `struct` and `end`. And you're referring to a value of type `t`.

Comment: @ivg, I know, I just wanted to find a way to modify the module. I agree with the last suggestion of Lucky, I think we have got the solution.